# JSON parse of string from cookie and ticking boxes doesn't tick boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, tampermonkey

I am writing a client side script to clean up the system that my college uses, and I am having an issue with a personal completion feature. What I have is an add-on that injects a `<script>` element into the DOM, and in this way I can modify the UI. However, I've run into an issue.

I have added some checkboxes to 'UnitBlocks' that allows me to check units that I have completed but the college hasn't uploaded yet. These trigger a JQuery event that allows me to tick the boxes and then change the color of the UnitBlock to yellow (see below for code):

```
var pc = false;
$(this).find('#personalCompletion').click(function(){ // personal completion is the checkboxId
    if (pc === false)
    {
        $(this).closest('a').css('background-color', '#FFCC45 !important');
        $(this).closest('a').children('p').text('Done');
        pc = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest('a').css('background-color', '');
        $(this).closest('a').children('p').text('In Progress');
        pc = false;
    }
    $(this).closest('p').append('   <input type="checkbox" id="personalCompletion"></input>'); //this re appends the checkbox
});
```

This works fine and it allows me to tick/untick the box. However, when I reload the page they dissapear, so I decided to store a cookie using JS with the tickbox values stored as `"302": "yes", "304": "no", "313": "yes"`. The numbers are the unit numbers and the yes/no is if the boxes are ticked or not (this cookie is manual and for testing purposes). My code then goes onto pull the cookie for each UnitBlock, and dependant on the yes/no value of the cookie, it sets the tick box (please see below for my code)

```
var cookieValues = getCookie('completedUnits');
for (var i = 0; i <= cookieValues.length; i++)
{
    if (cookieValues[i].includes($(this).attr('data-modcode'))) //data-modcode is a custom attribute with the unit number in (302 etc.)
    {
        if (cookieValues[i].text().indexOf('yes') >= 0) //if it includes the word 'yes'
        {
            $(this).find('#personalCompletion').attr('checked');
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't throw an error or anything, it just doesn't tick any boxes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `.prop()` method to change `checked` property (just like `selected` and `disabled` properties, too) representing and changing state of form elements.

There's big difference between `checked` property and `checked` attribute: the attribute represents `defaultChecked` property value, which is just initial state of the input, while the `checked` property changes state of the checkbox.

```js
$(function() {
  var $checkbox = $('#checkbox');

  $('.debug').text($('.debug').text() + '\n' +
                   $checkbox.attr('checked') + '\n' +   
                   $checkbox.prop('checked'));

  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

    $('.debug').text($('.debug').text() + '\n' +
                     $checkbox.prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```css
.debug {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click me!" />
<div class="debug"></div>
```